# Removeable battery-like "thing" that provide unlimited power for android phones

Tags: battery, charging

Is there this "thing", that have the shape of your android phone's battery, but does not hold any charges, and act as a unlimited power supply for your phone when your phone is plug into a socket?

Yeah, I think it is hard to describe this "thing" but in another words, it is a "thing" that have the shape of your battery for your android phone.

Normally, a phone battery contain charges (e.g. 1600 mAh) but this "thing" does not hold any charges. Basically you just put this "thing" into your phone and plug your phone into a socket outlet and this "thing" will act as a medium to keep your phone running -> meaning that you have unlimited battery life for your android phone as long as the power socket outlet is not switch off.

Of course, if you are going to somewhere and require portability, you just need to replace this "thing" with your normal phone battery. However, if you are going to be in one place for quite a long time, you just need to replace your normal phone battery with this "thing".

Also, you would not need to care for the battery life anymore as this "thing" act as a medium between the power socket outlet and your phone.

So, is there really such a "thing" right now or coming by the end of this year?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is related to [How to use android phone without battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/174862/131553)

IMO, the "thing" you visualise is "[not a thing](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/not_a_thing)
" (couldn't resist the pun) , since

1. Battery is *integral* to Android device (unlike an accessory) and the designed usage of device - both these are discussed in my answer to question linked above
2. Removeable batteries are being phased out , even in lower end devices, so the usage of that "thing" even if it exists,  is very limited

Whether such a "thing" is going to come in any time is open ended but unlikely for reasons above