# Is it possible to keep phone plugged in a powerbank when the battery is worn out?

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life

Is it possible to glue a powerbank to the back of a phone, and keep it plugged in permanently, if the battery has been worn out?

Comment: Related: [Removeable battery-like “thing” that provide unlimited power for android phones](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/176552/44325) and ultimately [Using Android phone without battery](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/174862/44325)

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that the answer is ***yes***.

For some devices, I have completely removed the battery and have them running just from the charger.

Of course, if there is a power outage, the device will immediately turn off without saving anything.  So be aware of that possibility.