# How to keep running Android tablet with dead battery

Tags: battery, charging

I‘m using Android Galaxy View tablet as photo-frame, integrated in the wall with AC adapter connected constantly 24/7. The problem is the battery inside tabled dies each year. And when the battery is broken the tablet switches off automatically, regardless of AC adaptor connected.
I tried to replace the battery last 4 years. Replaced 4 batteries already. But currently I cannot find any batteries for this device anymore. The tablet is not in production for many years already.
My question: is there way to avoid switching tablet off while it connected to AC with broken battery?
I‘m able to switch tablet on with power button. But it works this way - just several hours. Then it unexpectedly switching off. Looks like Android monitors the battery and shut downs the system if battery is 0%?. Can I disable this monitoring somehow?
Another question: can I change shutdown to reboot? The point is power button is hidden under glass frame covered the tablet. And it is not easy to press it when i need to switch the device on.

Comment: Hopefully helps, but becareful: [Using Android phone without battery](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/174862/44325)

Comment: If the tablet is rooted you can disable charging, this should also prevent the battery from dying, see e.g. https://android.stackexchange.com/q/54902/2241